# Apple Plist Error "Unexpected character 'b' at line 1"

Tags: ios, binary, plist

I'm having issues reading a binary PList. I'm using a windows computer and I've tried several pList readers. I really can't seem to get past the error "unexpected character 'b' at line 1".

Comment: Is it a binary plist?

Comment: @trojanfoe probably yes: the Apple binary plist format begins with the character sequence `bplist`. I can imagine that OP uses plist readers that can only interpret plists in textual (XML/OpenStep) format, but not binary plists.

Comment: Yup; I think the only recourse is to use `plutil -convert xml1 file.plist` on a Mac first.  Although there is something called `libplist` knocking about. See [this article](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Converting_Binary_Plists).

Comment: Plutil gives me a similar error. Let me get it for you. And iTunes bundles a windows equivalent to plutil fyi.

Comment: Plutil error: "Unexpected character b at line 1 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set".

Comment: @Ben: for what it's worth, I'm getting that same error on a plist file I extracted from a sqlite3 database from Final Cut Pro, on a Mac running MacOS Yosemite 10.10.5... So, it seems `plutil` doesn't recognize binary plists anymore?  Which seems awfully strange... or maybe there's some other detail.  Seems like maybe trying to use the `CoreFoundation` framework and reading it using a format of `kCFPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0`??  Though I'm also finding some hints of more recent versions of binary plists, so... ??  Anyway, you're not alone in seeing this error!

Comment: p.s.  See also, especially in case you want to try to read the file by writing code (I might try, we'll see): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413115/c-parse-binary-plist

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I previously made the mistake of editing the bplist with a text editor and reverting the change with said text editor afterwards. Even though the edited file looked exactly the same as the original in a text editor, their binary representation was not the same anymore.

This is why `plutil` failed to convert the file for me. Hope this helps someone!